# Store and Retrieve Records in Redis by Hour

Tags: redis

I'm trying to store phone call logs in Redis in a manner that I can quickly look them up by the phone number and by the timestamp (which is actually the number of hours since the unix epoch).

So the data is something like this:

```
Phone #     | Hour   | Data
------------+--------+-------------------
15551231234 | 386615 | "call record 1..."
15551231234 | 386615 | "call record 2..."
```

And I need to be able to get all the data for the specified phone number, and the hour within a range  (ex: the last 24 hours).

What is the best way in Redis to store and retrieve this form of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is not very good solution for arbitrary range queries: you would probably better served by a relational database or something like MongoDB.

Now, because your range queries applies on numerical values, you can use a zset (sorted set) to represent your data.

```
# adding a new call
ZADD <phone> <hour> <call data>

# find calls for a given phone number in a range
ZRANGEBYSCORE <phone> <hour begin> <hour end> WITHSCORES
```

Each returned item will be a pair with time stamp and call data.

Please note you cannot find all phone calls within a given range with this data structure (only calls for a given phone number within a range).